# merging with mismatch variables

Tags: sql, oracle, unix, sas, teradata

I want to use the variables from one SAS dataset and values from other SAS dataset to create a new SAS dataset. the two datasets do not have any matching variables except one, so joins would not work. I just want to import variables from 1st file and use as variables in 2nd file. the column no. and order is all same.

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: why join won't work?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please add anything you have tried so far and set up a minimally reproducible example. Here is a good place to start when asking questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Merge without a BY statement. Why all the different tags in your question?

Comment: Your question is simply too unclear to answer as it stands.  Please provide example data and desired output, and what code you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

Merging the dataset, 
how do you want to do it? do you just want to append? or do you want to join ? 
for a merge there is a need of having one common variable in each dataset you are trying to merge. 
for example.

```
dataset1 
Name Number
aaa   001
bbb   002
ccc   003

dataset2
Name age
aaa  15
bbb  17 
ccc  18
```

Now you can merge the datasets as there is a common variable "Name" 
else if there are same variables you can just use SET statement. 
Bevause if you dont have a common variable the datasets can be merged but you cannot know which records go to which key in the new dataset.

```
with common variable as name;
you sort the datasets with "by variable" i.e here its by name

data new_dataset;
merge dataset1 dataset2;
by name;
run;
```

else you will not know which is going to what...!

Comment: I imported a file with 'GETNAMES=NO' and now i want to rename my new data set with those variable names. when i imported the file SAS created automatic variables A-Z and now after creating  a final dataset i want to use those actual varaibles name instead of automatic variables created by SAS.   Thanks!